# A problem from "A book of abstract algebra" by C.Pinter

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

It seems to me that the problem C.4 on the page 319 in the above mentioned book is incorrect.

The problem reads:
*If c is a complex root of a cubic $a(x)\in Q[x]$ then $Q(c)$ is the root field of $a(x)$.*

As far as I know this depends on discriminant of $a(x)$, i.e. the statement is true if the discriminant is a square of a rational number.

Am I right ? What am I missing ?

Comment: What does the term *root field* mean? I like to think I'm relatively familiar with basic field theory and Galois theory, but I don't think *root field* is standard terminology.

Comment: I think "root field" means "splitting field". In world, we are asked to show that $a(x)$ splits in $Q(c)$.

Comment: Suppose $a$ is irreducible. Let $D$ be the discriminant and $K$ be the splitting field. The statement is false when $\sqrt{D}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$. Note that $\sqrt{D}\in K$ is quadratic and $c$ is cubic, so $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=6$ and thus $\mathbb{Q}(c)\ne K$.